# Nestjs Jest Unit Test: Basic test failure - Jest configuration

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I have a simple Jest test for my Nest JS project.

The Jest looks like:

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { IbmVpcController } from './ibm.vpc.controller';
import { IbmVpcServiceMock } from './ibm.vpc.service.mock';
import { ModuleMocker, MockFunctionMetadata } from 'jest-mock';
import { MOCKED_VPC } from '../../repository/ibm/mock.vpc.data';

const moduleMocker = new ModuleMocker(global);

describe('IbmVpcController', () => {
  let controller: IbmVpcController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [IbmVpcController],
      providers: [IbmVpcServiceMock]
    })
      .useMocker((token) => {
        if (token === IbmVpcServiceMock) {
          return {
            list: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(MOCKED_VPC.VPCs),
            get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(MOCKED_VPC.VPCs[0]),
            create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(MOCKED_VPC.VPCs[0]),
            update: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(MOCKED_VPC.VPCs[0]),
          };
        }
        if (typeof token === 'function') {
          const mockMetadata = moduleMocker.getMetadata(token) as MockFunctionMetadata<any, any>;
          const Mock = moduleMocker.generateFromMetadata(mockMetadata);
          return new Mock();
        }
      })
      .compile();

    controller = module.get<IbmVpcController>(IbmVpcController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

My `jest.config.js` looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  roots: ["./src"],
  transform: { "\\.ts$": ["ts-jest"] },
  testRegex: "(/__test__/.*|(\\.|/)(spec))\\.ts?$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
  ],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: {
        // allow js in typescript
        allowJs: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

However it is failing with the following error:

```
 FAIL  apps/protocols/src/ibm/vpc/ibm.vpc.controller.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                                
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\Users\pradipm\clients\CloudManager\cm_6\occm\client-infra\nest-services\node_modules\axios\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/retry-axios/src/index.ts:124:1)
```

Now able to get it what I am missing in my typescript Nest's Jest configuration.

Basically I tried out some more options also:

1. I tried out specifying the transformIgnorePatterns as only '/node_modules/'.
2. Tried out excluding the lodash-es', 'axios'
3. Tried out `transformIgnorePattens` as '/lib/' (where axois is there)
4. Added `allowJs: true` in the tsconfig.app.json `compileOptions`.

Any help to get trough my first basic test would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With axios version 1.1.2 there's a bug with jest](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5101). You can resolve it by adding `moduleNameMapper: { '^axios$': require.resovle('axios') }` to your `jest` configuration

Comment: Any idea if my jest configuration is in TypeScript how to add this line in TypeScript?